# Array generate in one single line

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I generate an array of DataColumn in one single line?

```dart
<DataColumn>[
  DataColumn(label: Text('A')),
  DataColumn(label: Text('B')),
  DataColumn(label: Text('C')),
  DataColumn(label: Text('D')),
]
```

Such as:

```dart
list<DataColumn>.gen(['A','B','C','D'], (string) => DataColumn(label: Text(string)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `List.generate()` like is:

```dart
List<String> stringList = ['ACTIVE', 'MODE', 'SEMI', 'AUTO'];

Colum(children: List.generate(stringList.length, (int index) => DataColumn(label: Text(stringList[index])));
```

Comment: On this way don't forget to add .toList() like List.generate(...).toList()

Comment: Huh?  `List.generate` already generates a `List`, so `.toList()` wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: As I commented below, it's preferable for `stringList` to be declared as `static const`. In fact most IDEs will prompt you to do just that.

Comment: @RoslanAmir That's assuming that `stringList` is declared at class scope.  `static` doesn't make sense if it's a top-level variable or a local variable.

Comment: @jamedlin, right. In that case it should be declared as `final`. I am suggesting this because this answer will be read in the future by others and should be using best practices.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Iterable.map`:

```dart
var columns = ['A', 'B','C', 'D'].map((s) => DataColumn(label: Text(s))).toList();
```

or collection-`for`, which is slightly shorter:

```dart
var columns = [for (var s in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']) DataColumn(label: Text(s))];
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution, but two lines.

```
var titles = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
List.generate(titles.length,(index) => DataColumn(label: Text(titles[index])));
```

Comment: `titles` should be declared as `static const` not `var`.